# IE8 getElementById quirks mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, quirks-mode

I have this function defined in my  in my JSP:

```
function addcolor(){
    alert("found " + document.getElementById("clrCd").value);
}
```

my HTML (from struts 1.3 app)

```
<input type="text" name="clrCd" maxlength="2" size="2" value="">
<input type="button" name="add" value="ADD" onclick="addcolor()">
```

when my browser is in quirks mode, and I click the ADD button, I get the alert with the value of the text input

if I put my browser into IE8 standards mode (via F12 console) and run the same code, I get:

> Error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or
>   undefined

why on earth is this happening....I've lost an entire day to dealing with IE and all it's bullshit.

this is a legacy app and I can't really change much, but I'd really like to get them off quirks mode so we can start using some HTML5 features like bootstrap and angularJS.

any ideas?

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't "IE bullshit", it's that you don't have an element with any id `clrCd`.  You've only set the name attribute.

Add an `id="clrCd"` to your element, and you will have more luck.

Comment: yeah....fighting all the other IE-isms coupled with struts TLDs hiding me from the HTML got in my way.  sorry for the rant (even though IE *does* suck).  I had to use "styleId" in the struts nested.tld which turns into the ID attribute.  It was driving me nuts because it was working in quirks mode and not IE8 standards mode.....regardless....thanks again for the quick and helpful reply

Comment: I know this is old, but I figured I might be able to help the next guy.  When IE is in quirks mode, getElementById( foo ) will return an element with ID="foo" *OR* NAME="foo".  I turned off quirks mode so I could fix up the CSS and it broke the scripts.

Comment: @Jason, Wow!  I had no idea that was possible.  You should add it as an answer and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually You can do this before IE7 
See document

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536437(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. In IE8 Standards mode, getElementById performs a case-sensitive match on the ID attribute only. In IE7 Standards mode and previous modes, this method performs a case-insensitive match on both the ID and NAME attributes